# What's wrong with my JNLP security?

Tags: java, security, md5, jnlp, java-web-start

Starting with some fairly recent version of the JRE, I'm no longer able to do MD5 hashes inside JNLP programs.  It throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.  If I run the same application as a "normal" (non-JNLP) application, it works fine.  The stack trace looks like this:

```
com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
com.myapp.md5Hash(myapp.java:68)
```

Best guess is that I'm getting denied due to some security issue?  Not sure why though.  We've already the JNLP fixup code in place (to fix the JNLP linking issues).  Ideas?

Current method called just does a MessageDigest instance of "MD5".  I've also tried the `DigestUtils` methods.  Same problem either way.

Comment: Am I a bad person if I find it highly ironic that a program called **JNLP** is throwing Java Null Pointer Exceptions?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - not so much 'bad' as 'newbie giggling immature'.  I'd have hoped for better from a moderator.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: More proof that people can be insulted by almost anything.

Comment: JaNeLA is really cool, I'd never heard of it before!  Unfortunately, whatever the issue is, it doesn't detect it at this time.

Comment: Try searching the [bug DB](http://bugs.sun.com/) & if you find nothing similar, raise a new report.  See what Oracle has to say on the matter.  I've been hearing around Q's on SO of a number of seeming glitches in the 1.7.0_25 JRE.

Comment: Update: Twiddled JNLP settings as suggest elsewhere, no change.  Migrated from a library to bundling the classes inside the main jar, also no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be any way around this.  MD5 has now been replaced with a proprietary algorithm to do what we need (no need for panic, it's not something that requires a strong hashing method).